# Sailsjs - Default route permissions

Tags: sails.js

By default, Sails offers access to these routes:

> ## Backbone Conventions
>
> ```
> GET   :    /:controller            => findAll() <- THIS ACTION
> GET   :    /:controller/read/:id        => find(id)
> POST  :    /:controller/create        => create()
> POST  :    /:controller/create/:id        => create(id)
> PUT   :    /:controller/update/:id        => update(id)
> DELETE:    /:controller/destroy/:id    => destroy(id)
> ```
>
> (taken from then documentation).

In order to set up permissions, config/policies.js can be edited, and permissions can be added like this:

```
ControllerName: {
    '*': false,
    update: true,
    destroy: true   
}
```

How to set up permissions for the default get action ? (the one that results in an findAll() action).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the find blueprint method like this:

```
ControllerName: {
'*': false,
update: true,
destroy: true,
find: true  
}
```

Comment: I will check this than come back with an answer. Thanks.